# maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: ffmpeg

Can someone help me figure out why FFMPEG keeps failing? I am running the command in PHP using exec. The exit code is 1.

command:

```
ffmpeg -i uploads/5566963704760/IMG_1806.MOV -vf scale="320:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" uploads/5566963704760/cropped.mp4
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
libavutil 52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec 55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat 55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice 55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter 4. 2.100 / 4. 2.100
libswscale 2. 5.102 / 2. 5.102
libswresample 0. 18.100 / 0. 18.100
libpostproc 52. 3.100 / 52. 3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'uploads/5566963704760/IMG_1806.MOV':
Metadata:
major_brand : qt
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: qt
creation_time : 2015-05-26 00:48:52
make : Apple
make-eng : Apple
encoder : 8.3
encoder-eng : 8.3
date : 2015-05-25T17:48:23-0700
date-eng : 2015-05-25T17:48:23-0700
location : +37.3248-121.9063+027.720/
location-eng : +37.3248-121.9063+027.720/
model : iPhone 4S
model-eng : iPhone 4S
Duration: 00:00:04.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 784 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2015-05-26 00:48:52
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 568x320, 705 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
Metadata:
rotate : 90
creation_time : 2015-05-26 00:48:52
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
[libx264 @ 0x1632a40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
Output #0, mp4, to 'uploads/5566963704760/cropped.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : qt
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: qt
model-eng : iPhone 4S
make : Apple
make-eng : Apple
encoder : 8.3
encoder-eng : 8.3
date : 2015-05-25T17:48:23-0700
date-eng : 2015-05-25T17:48:23-0700
location : +37.3248-121.9063+027.720/
location-eng : +37.3248-121.9063+027.720/
model : iPhone 4S
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 320x180, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 24 tbc (default)
Metadata:
rotate : 90
creation_time : 2015-05-26 00:48:52
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2015-05-26 00:48:52
handler_name : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Usually the console output provides the actual error, but I don't see it in your output. Perhaps it's a broken build. Can you test a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)? I'm guessing you don't want to actually re-encode the audio, so add `-c:a copy`. Also, you can replace `trunc(ow/a/2)*2` with `-2`. Lastly, the stream `rotate` metadata will be copied. Some players will use that and others will ignore it. One option is to physically rotate the video, since you're filtering anyway, and strip the metadata. I can provide more details about that later.

Comment: I've tested other builds of FFMPEG locally, and they work fine with the video I am using. The problem is that I'm stuck with using the build on a shared hosting server. How can I figure out whether the build is broken without access to a terminal?

Comment: What does "ffmpeg -codecs | grep 264" give?

Comment: DEV.LS h264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )

Comment: Does adding `-f mp4 -c:v libx264` to the command before the output file name help?

Comment: No, it produced the same error.

Comment: You're stuck with that build, but it seems broken. I don't think there is anything you can do if you **must** use the allegedly broken build.

Comment: Is there anything I could tell my hosting company that would convince them that it's broken?

Comment: Just tell them that the version is outdated and contains known bugs. Also, there have been lots of security related releases since that one.